# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Dashboards not permitting me to embed them in iFrame on my website by using React Apps

Tags: reactjs, dynamics-crm

```
<iframe src="http://prodCRM" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts
allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-top-navigation"
width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

When embedding any of the above links in an `IFrame` I got the following:

`On Premises` CRM shows in `IFrame` that 'This content cannot be displayed in a frame.'.

Comment: Did you check the `Select whether to restrict cross-frame scripting` option in the `IFrame` control settings? Did this error only show for `IE`?

Comment: Security constraint. I cannot allow third-party URLs in Microsoft Dynamic CRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by manually Uploading the index.html and main.js as a web resource once, so you can include them as a web resource (IFRAME). Then deploy and publish the just built bundled and minified files to the Dynamics 365 CE server.

https://crm-rocks.com/reactjs-as-dynamics-365-ce-web-resource/